# Jest Testing React Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am new to testing and have been trying to solve this problem for a while now.  Although I can find similar posts I haven't found anything that has worked for me.  I think the issue might be because my AppContext is set up a bit differently than others.

I have an AppContext that looks like this:

```
const AppContext = React.createContext();

export class AppContextProvider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      predefinedRoles: [
        {role_type : "2nd Project Manager", profile: {user: {first_name : '', last_name: ''}}}, 
        {role_type : "Executive Sponsor", profile: {user: {first_name : '', last_name: ''}}}, 
        {role_type : "CFO or Finance Contact", profile: {user: {first_name : '', last_name: ''}}},
        {role_type : "OI & T Contact", profile: {user: {first_name : '', last_name: ''}}},
        {role_type : "Payroll Contact", profile: {user: {first_name : '', last_name: ''}}},
        {role_type : "Human Resources Contact", profile: {user: {first_name : '', last_name: ''}}}
      ],
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContext.Provider
        value={{
          predefinedRoles: this.predefinedRoles,
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </AppContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export const withContext = Component => {
  return function AppContextComponent(props) {
    return (
      <AppContext.Consumer>
        {globalState => <Component {...globalState} {...props} />}
      </AppContext.Consumer>
    );
  };
};
```

What I want to do is test whether these Context values are being mapped properly into another component.

Here is my mapping component:

```
export const AssignRoles = props => {
  const predefinedRoles = props
  return (
            <div className={styles.rolesPage} id="assign-roles-roles-page">
          {predefinedRoles.map((roles, id)=> {
              return(<AssignRolesCard organizationRoles={roles} key={id} handleFormOpen={handleFormOpen} updateCreateOrEdit={updateCreateOrEdit}/>)
          })}
        </div>
  )
}

export default withContext(AssignRoles);
```

I have been trying to write a test which checks if AssignRoles is rendering but I get a failure saying 'cannot read property map of undefined'.

I have tried several different combinations of the below code using `<AppContext>` `<AppContext.Provider>` `<AppContext.Consumer>` but I still can't get my test to pass successfully.

```
let predefinedRoles = [
    {name : "2nd Project Manager", assigned : false}, 
    {name : "Executive Sponser", assigned: false}, 
    {name : "CFO or Finance Contact", assigned: false},
    {name : "OI&T Contact", assigned: false},
    {name : "Payroll Contact", assigned: false},
    {name : "HR Contact", assigned: false}
]

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<AppContext value={predefinedRoles}><AssignRoles /></AppContext>, div);
});
```

I've been looking at the React testing Library docs [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-context) and trying everything I can think of to match what they have done but I still haven't succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

That's should be straight forward, no matter enzyme or react testing library.
Wrap your test component under the provider component.

`const componentUnderTest = <AppContextProvider {..allPropsYouNeed}>
<Foo />
</AppContextProvider>`

With react-testing-library, you test whether the desired actions or element got rendered with passed context values you need(like if color got changed or rendering differed etc).

With enzyme(mount), you can observe same. But if you want to manually check the props of the component, you can't(as enzyme only allows inspection of props of root component and not children) and you **shouldn't**. After all the testing is about how your component should behave and not what it takes. (react-testing-library principle)

Comment: This doesn't quite work.  I'm not totally sure what "..allPropsYouNeed" would be here.  I need to pass in the array `predefinedRoles` and have that array come through as props on the component.